# Configure htaccess to ignore anything after last slash

Tags: .htaccess

i removed images extension from URL :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.png [NC,L]
```

but i need to ignore anything after images URL for ex :

if i add a random after last slash images url :

[mysite/images/imagename/z54zrg89zgz98gzg](http://mysite/images/imagename/z54zrg89zgz98gzg)

the images must be work.

i tried this line but doesn't work :

RewriteRule mysite/images/(*)/^ - [L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# For /images/ directory:
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)(?:/.*)$ images/$1.png [NC,L]

# For others (If necessary)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.png [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi croises can you help me please i write my problem in this online text saver can you check it please 
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/245x